# Detect capitalization of a string and apply it to another string in PHP

Tags: php, string

As the title suggests i'm trying to detect the capitalization of a string and apply that same formatting to a new string.

Example:
`Yellow cheese` >>> detect that it's only the first character capitalized >>> change `blue cheese` to `Blue cheese`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps you could save some time and just capitalize for all strings, using ucwords (all first letters of each string token) or ucfirst (only the first letter).
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try :

```
$ref = 'Yellow cheese';
$str = 'blue cheese';
$ref_words = explode(' ', $ref);
$str_words = explode(' ', $str);
for($i=0; $i<count($ref_words); $i++) {
    if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]/', $ref_words[$i])) {
        $str_words[$i] = ucfirst($str_words[$i]);
    }
}
$res = implode(' ', $str_words);
echo $res,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
Blue cheese
```

Answer (score 3):

Kind of depends on how smart you need the algorithm to be. A simple one could be simply something like:

```
<?php
$v1 = "Yellow cheese";
$v2 = "blue cheese";
$out = "";
for($i = 0; $i < max(strlen($v1), strlen($v2)); $i++) {
  if($v1[i] === strtoupper($v1[i])) {
    $out .= strtoupper($v2[i]);
  } else {
    $out .= strtolower($v2[i]);
  }
}
```

This will do it very blindly, so

```
  YelLoW ChEEse
> BluE CHEsSE
```